# Print a Google Charts [map module] with no data / pinpoint

Tags: google-maps, maps, google-visualization

I use Google Charts to print a map with some pinpoints.
Sometimes it happens that I have no data to show up, so I want to print just the maps, with no data / no pinpoints.

if I use:

```
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart', 'map']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([[]]);

    var options = {
        zoomLevel: 2,
        showTip: true,
        streetViewControl: false
    }

    var map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('map_container'));
    map.draw(data, options);
}
```

It just returns error:

> The columns type does not match the supported data format. See
>   documentation for supported formats.

If I set

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Lat', 'Long'], [null, null]]);
```

It draws a gray box with error:

> No data points to show on map

How can I draw a map using Google Charts with no pinpoint?

Comment: On which browsers are you seeing this issue?

Comment: Firefox 38, IE11, Chrome 43

Comment: Apparently there's a bug for it: https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/968